# fetch unique keys based on values in reactjs

Tags: javascript

I have the following Object:

```
{
  "Size": {
    "L": [
      "Men clothing",
      "Women clothing",
      "Toys"
    ],
    "M": [
      "Women clothing"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a function which returns the size keys which contains the given category.

For example, when I pass `Men clothing` I need expect the function to return `["L"]`. I pass  `Men clothing` and `Women clothing`, I need the result to be `["L", "M"]`.

Comment: This looks like a `Size` is an object instead of Array, you can you Object.keys(Size) to get array of all the keys [L,M] and then check values

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to obtain the keys which contain the given string. This is one of them:

```js
const collection = {
  "Size": {
    "L": [
      "Men clothing",
      "Women clothing",
      "Toys"
    ],
    "M": [
      "Women clothing"
    ]
  }
}

function getSizes(obj, categories) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => {
    return categories.some(category => obj[key].includes(category));
  });
}

console.log(getSizes(collection.Size, ['Men clothing']));
console.log(getSizes(collection.Size, ['Men clothing', 'Women clothing']));
```